# docmd.transferspreadsheet incorrectly assigning Data Type

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using the following code to import data from an Excel file into access.

```
Private Sub cmdOriginal_Click()

Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
Dim varFile As Variant

Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fDialog

  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .Title = "Please select a file"
  .Filters.Clear
  .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.XLSX"
  .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

If .Show = True Then

For Each varFile In .SelectedItems

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, "OriginalData", varFile, True, ""
Beep
MsgBox "Import Complete!", vbExclamation, ""

Next
Else
     MsgBox "You clicked Cancel in the file dialog box."
End If

End With

End Sub
```

It works well for the most part, however in some cases I'm finding that it incorrectly sets the data type of a field to number. This then causes import failures as the data being imported actually contains both text and numbers. Creating the table in advance isn't an option because the field names are different for each file I import.

I'd appreciate any suggestion of how I can get past this.

Regards,
Adam

Answer (score 2):

Access makes it's best guess as to what the data type should be. An old trick is to insert a dummy row below your headers in the Excel file. In the offending columns put an example of the data type you require, so for a string put something like "abd123". If you don't want to do that manually it could easily be automated within Excel or from Access itself (create an Excel app object, open the file, make the adjustment & save before your code does the upload). Then you can simply delete these rows from the table with a delete query containing the dummy string as a criteria. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll give that a try

Answer (score 1):

Two methods you could use:

1. Manually import the table, and modify fields datatype and other properties, to your needs. You can then, in code, delete table's data before importing new data into it. This is better when you need the data in you system, for further process.
2. Link to the Excel, and have a query upon it, casting the fields to desired field data types, and names. This option lets you know (invokes an error) if data can not be casted, but data stays in Excel.