# Access VBA - Import problems

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm importing some data form Excel into Access and I'm facing some strange issues.

Problem:

I'm using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Method to import Excel data into Access like this :

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Excel_Data", "Filename", True
```

This "Excel_Data" table is not pre-created so Access creates It on It's own. Why ? If I pre-create It, then User has to import data to Destination table from Excel in exactly same order (column A in Excel is row 1 in Access etc..).

But If you don't pre-create It, then Access creates whatever table there is in Excel and you can Import only data that you wish - based on column names. Now here is where It get's stucked....

I don't know why, but on every other Imports I do like this, Access creates only Text fields - and then my Import to destination table works.

But in one of the Imports Access creates a Number field, and then Import into destination table doesn't work anymore. All Excel data are formatted as general.

Does anybody know how to avoid this ???

Basically I want just to Import excel data into Access, based on column names, in whatever column order there is in Excel.

thanks for help !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docmd.transferspreadsheet incorrectly assigning Data Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130284/docmd-transferspreadsheet-incorrectly-assigning-data-type)

Comment: No, that's not my thread. But a simmilar problem, yes. I've figured out If you manually format all excel numeric data to text that It works. But I want some kind of automated solution. Can it be done ?

Comment: The linked question has answers with multiple suggested solutions to your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Comment: Access' `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport` method has to make assumptions about the data type of the columns it's importing... I think it does this by looking at the first 10 or so rows of the column in your spreadsheet and bases it on that. If it's assuming numeric when you want text, perhaps sort the spreadsheet on the offending column so that data that *looks* like text rather than numeric is at the top and see if that helps.

Comment: This is terrible behaviour. Problems are only numeric data. But I can't figure out why in some cases Access creates a Text field instead of Number. I have 2 different spreadsheets : in both there are numeric values in 1st column, and both columns formatted to General. Only difference is length of numbers for 2 digits, but Access creates a Text field for one spreadsheet, and Number field for other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all answers, but I have solved this on my own. Best thing to avoid any problems when doing Import is simply using ALTER Table command after DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet method is done. I just altered all my columns to Text format, changed all my other tables to Text fields and now every manipulating with data works just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed my comment to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the query like this instead of `TransferSpreadsheet`

```
SELECT * INTO Table1 
  FROM [Sheet1$D3:E24] 
    IN "C:\Temp\Test.xls" [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1];
```

Note, that IMEX=1 allows you to suppress data type guessing and Access will create always text fields.

Also this will allow you to import data from specified ranges of spreadsheet and use WHERE clause for filtering unnecessary data

Comment: I'm trying to make your code working, but It's not working. I need to put variable "Filename" instead of exact file location like "C:\Temp\Test.xls". And still, your solution didn't work for me, I need to put apostrophe in correct order in VBA, but don't know how.

Comment: Create SQL text as string and use your variable: `strSQL="INSERT... IN '" & Filename & "' [..."` and then run it: `CurrentDB.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError`. Didn't catch about apostrophe. If you talk about quotes around file name, just use single quotes as I proposed in this comment, there are two quotes - single and double toghther

Comment: I tried, but It doesn't work for me, my import code is quite long, maybe something is wrong there. I guess I'll just have to be carefull when Access creates data types on It's own. I have allready set all tables to number fields where needed, nad now It works. Now I'm just waiting to see where problems might occur, so far nothing on the horizon.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work? What is the error?  Try test data first, with few rows. This method works fine in number of my applications, I don't use TransferSpreadsheet at all

Comment: I apologize, typed manually, made mistake in first row of SQL. Please try again

Comment: It doesn't do anything, that's what I mean. If I create table or not. I have code that does a lot of queries and checking of Excel file before Transfersheet method, maybe that is cause.

Comment: I changed query in the answer, try again. The best way to check - insert SQL string, which generates your VBA code to query builder and run it. It will give you error or insert the data